# Naming convention (Singular or plural name class)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a *class* that modelizes a Shop. So it has the following attributes:

- name
- description
- address
- phone
- ... etc.

Should I have to name it **ShopInfo** or **ShopInfos**?

Any link to a *naming convention*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an object of the class, it is only the information **for one** shop.
The object describes one shop info.
It is common to use to write a class name that way, that it makes **sense when using an object**.

Especially in method names and declaring variables it is clearer

```
    // CORRECT WAY
    - (UIAlertView *)calculateSomething:(UIView I)view {
        UIView *newView = view;
        ...
        return [UIAlertView alertWith...];
    }
```

It would be very odd to use the plural form in my opinion (it seems like the single object is more than one!):

```
    // BAD IDEA
    - (UIAlertViews *)calculateSomething:(UIViews *)view {
        UIViews *newView = view;
        ...
        return [UIAlertViews alertWith...];
    }
```

You can then easily use the object or test for the class and it makes sense too:

```
    [myObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]
```

Here is the official link how you should write a name:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-BBCHBFAH

And there you see, Apple always **avoids using the plural** form (NSString, NSArray, etc.).

*Of course, the other way around it also makes sense, but then more for class methods etc. Other popular languages also use singular form for classes.*

---

Some other good coding guidelines are from *CocoaDevCentral*

http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000082.php

http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000083.php

Answer (score 3):

ShopInfo would be correct, ShopInfos would be useful for for example an array of ShopInfo, but it won't be recommended because names similitude can bring confusion.

Comment: Thanks Antonio, in the case of an array of ShopInfo, what naming convention would you use or recommend? arrayShopInfo or something similar?