# How should documentation refer to the plural of a type name?

Tags: types, documentation, comments, naming

In commenting or documenting code, I often find it useful to refer to the plural of a type's name, but I am unsure what is the most readable and least ambiguous way to do this.  For instance, if I have a class named Dog, it might seem natural to say "All Dogs have woof() methods".  But what if I also have a class named "Dogs" that can contain multiple instances of type Dog.  Is it confusing to say "Dogs" in reference to multiple things of type Dog as opposed to a single thing of type Dogs?

Note that I am not asking what the type naming convention should be, but how to refer to the type in comments or documentation external to the code.

I have found English grammar rules that sometimes allow 's to be used in forming a plural.  For instance, "Do's and Don'ts", or "I got all A's", but it doesn't look right to me to say "All Dog's have woof() methods".  This may seem like a silly question, but it has caused me grief many times over the years.

Comment: This is an interesting question but most likely to lead to a variety of opinions as I don't believe there is a single straight answer to this problem.  This subject was already partially covered in this topic: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/103720/classes-naming-singular-or-plural

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Naming convention (Singular or plural name class)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464559/naming-convention-singular-or-plural-name-class)

Comment: @ekscrypto No duplicate, this is about documentation, your link is about code.

Comment: Might be worthwhile looking into some official documentation of, e.g., Microsoft, to see how they deal with this.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly opinion based, but I'd consider `all Dogs have` very confusing. I'd much rather see the class name typeset differently or quoted somehow, e.g., `all 'Dog's have` or, if room allows, the still clearer (and easier to read) `all Dog instances have`.

Comment: Do not, under any circumstances, change the spelling or capitalization of a literal name! Use quotes as shown above to pluralize, this makes it very clear that you are adorning a name to make it look nice. Your job is to document the code *as is* not as you would like it to be.

Comment: Do you happen to know whether 'Dog's is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 0):

Approaching this from a linguistic angle, I would expect a simple apostrophe to suffice. For example, according to the *Chicago Manual of Style* the [rules for plurals of letters are as follows](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/25280/12232):

> Capital letters used as words, numerals used as nouns, and
>   abbreviations usually form the plural by adding s. **To aid
>   comprehension**, lowercase letters **form the plural with an apostrophe
>   and an s**.

Extrapolating that in the case of ambiguity an apostrophe is allowed, this seems to me to be a grammatically correct solution. For example, multiple instances of the letter A would also be called A's.

Also, [some argue using the apostrophe for possession would be undesirable either way](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/100073/12232), so there would be no real confusion if you never refer to Dog's in the possessive form:

> So, in all, "The car's antenna" is fine, "The antenna of the car"
>   would still be favoured by some, and "Its antenna" is also fine,
>   though the KJV would have used "the antenna thereof".

It might be worthwhile asking this on [English Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/). From a quick look around most grammatical rules on plurals are rather specific (e.g., names of people) and do not apply directly to class names.